# Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with pdf $f(x) = ke^{-|x|}$ for $-\infty<x<\infty$; find $k$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with pdf $f(x) = ke^{-|x|}$ for $-\infty<x<\infty$; find $k$.

By the rules of a pdf, I have to integrate 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{k}{e^{|x|}} = 1.$$

Then I get $$\frac{-k\cdot x}{(e^{|x|}|x|)}\Bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}.$$

Now this is where I'm not exactly sure if what I am doing is correct

I take the integral from $0$ to infinity and multiply it by $2$ and I equate $|x| = x$ so they cancel each other out; we get $2\cdot (-k)/(e^{|x|})$

$2\cdot(-k)x/(e^{|x|}|x|)$ and then I evaluate from $0$ to infinity.  Plugging in infinity we get

$2\cdot(-k)/(e^{|\infty|})) = 0$

plug in $0$: $2\cdot(-k)/(e^{|0|})  = -2k$

then $0 - (-2k) = 1$ and $k = 1/2$.

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Format your posts. Always. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of even getting an antiderivative, notice that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|} dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^x dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-x} dx$$

and then compute these two (easy) integrals.

Comment: Isn't this what Auron does from
"i take the integral from $0$ to $\inf$ and multiply it by $2$ and i equate $|x| = x$ so they cancel eachout eachother we get $-2\frac{k}{e^{|x|}}$" and onwards

Comment: @Hetebrij Oh, I misunderstood the grouping with the messed up formatting. I'll redact that part.

Comment: ok i got the same answer for K using your method as well i hope this is  correct method for solving for k, thanks for tip on solving absolutes tho it will probably help me in the future

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate, or I think you can proceed as follows. Assuming $k>0$, by symmetry, 
$$1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty ke^{-|x|}\,dx = 2k\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx=2k$$
where $e^{-x}$ is the density of an exponential distribution with mean $1$. Hence $k=1/2$